# user profile 2 new phone fields

Tags: php, jquery, osclass

Hi guys how do i add 2 new phone fields on the user profile page on Osclass?

This is what i try already!

I the database i add 2 new fields in the t_user
s_phone_mobile2
s_phome_mobile3

oc-content/themes/ctg_housing/user-profile.php

```
<label class="control-label" for="phoneMobile2">
  <?php _e('2 Mobile #', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
  (<?php _e('optional', 'ctg_housing'); ?>)
</label>
<?php UserForm::phone_mobile2_text(osc_user()); ?>
<label class="control-label" for="phoneMobile3">
  <?php _e('3 Mobile #', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
  (<?php _e('optional', 'ctg_housing'); ?>)
</label>
<?php UserForm::phone_mobile3_text(osc_user()); ?>
```

oc-includes/osclass/UserActions.php

```
$input['s_phone_mobile2'] = trim(Params::getParam('s_phone_mobile2'));
$input['s_phone_mobile3'] = trim(Params::getParam('s_phone_mobile3'));
```

Hope someone can help!

Thanks